# How can I breakdown a row in csv with pandas in python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm working with csv on pandas. I'm trying to break a row like this:

```
| col1  | col2  | jan | feb | mar |
|-------|-------|-----|-----|-----|
| name1 | place | 23  | 32  | 42  |
| name2 | place | 43  | 666 | 3   |
| name3 | place | 2   | 532 | 420 |
```

into this:

```
| col1  | col2  |months | quantity |
|-------|-------|-------|----------|
| name1 | place | jan   | 23       |
| name1 | place | feb   | 32       |
| name1 | place | mar   | 42       |
| name2 | place | jan   | 43       |
| name2 | place | feb   | 666      |
| name2 | place | mar   | 3        |
| name3 | place | jan   | 2        |
| name3 | place | feb   | 532      |
| name3 | place | mar   | 420      |
```

any function to breakdown rows on pandas?

`pandas.melt()` does not work as i want, because it does not create the order i intended.

Comment: This is a typical case of `unpivot` or in pandas we call it `melt`. Use the following to get your output: `pd.melt(df, id_vars=['col1', 'col2'])`

Comment: @Erfan while `melt` yields the same *set* of data, orders are different from what OP asks for, which may or may not be important.

Comment: @QuangHoang Just add `.sort_values('col1')`

Comment: @DYZ really? What if `col1` is not ordered in original dataframe?

Comment: @QuangHoang Then, no :)

Comment: `sort_values()``is not intuitive for the order i want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df.set_index(['col1','col2']).stack().reset_index()
```

You may need to rename some columns afterwards.